# Create public key from Private key

Tags: certificates

Is it possible to create public key from Private key? In Microsoft certificate console (Capi) you can export a certificate out of a private key. Is this exported certificate a public key? I know that the CA who issued the private key can also issue the public key but just want to know if the certificate within Private key is effectively also Public key?

Comment: yes, it is the only way, first generated pub, key and then public. Both represent key pair. Read how to generate RSA key pair using openssl.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me right, RSA public keys are the first half of the private key, so it should be possible. You don't mention the encryption scheme used in this Microsoft system, but I recommend you find out and read up on some technical documentation to find out your next steps. Good luck.